# Zend FrameWork Production Deloyment whitescreen

Tags: php, zend-framework, dev-to-production

I had moved my zend framework 1.11.11 project to production server windows 2012.
while running i am getting whitepage only.pls help on this site is not working for 3 days.

steps have done for deployment.

1. downloaded XAMPP
2. downloaded zendframework 1.11.11 and copied bin folder pasted in php folder as zend-bin,copied library and pasted in php/ext/
3. also passed in project folder
4. made env path for zend-bin dir
5. restarted the server

have attached screenshot below.[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: did you check the **error log** ?

Comment: @GaryHoubre i don't have access to the code ryt now

Comment: @Ermenegildo please tell me how to check error log